# NMEA data parsing using python 2.7

Tags: python-2.7

i want readings of present GPS location, when i run the below code in raspberry pi,  program prints 10-12 outputs and then it displays the error as below: 
  **Traceback (most recent call last):

  File "simplegpsparsing.py", line 24, in 

    get_present_gps() 

  File "simplegpsparsing.py", line 16, in get_present_gps

    lat, _, lon= line.split(',')[2:5]

ValueError: need more than 0 values to unpack**

i want present value of GPS( buffers should be updated with immediate GPS) so that present GPS  values can be known.
my code goes as below :

```
import os
import serial
def get_present_gps:
    ser= serial.Serial('/dev/ttyAMA0',9600)
    ser.open()
    while True :
        f=open('/home/pi/Desktop/gps1','w')
        data=ser.read(ser.inWaiting()) # read no.of bytes in waiting
        f.write(data) #write data into file
        f.flush() # flush(method) from buffer into os buffer
        os.fsync(f.fileno()) #ensure to write from os buffer(internal buffers)into disk
        f = open('/home/pi/Desktop/gps1','r') # fetch the required file
        for line in f.read().split('\n') :  
            if line.startswith( '$GPGGA' ) :
                lat, _, lon = line.strip().split(',')[2:5]
                try :
                    lat = float( lat )
                    lon = float( lon )
                    print lat
                    print lon
                except :
                    pass

         # something wrong happens with your data, print some error messages
get_present_gps()
```

if the serial port is left open without closing, will it create any problem? will  the above code meet my requirement i.e getting the instantaneous value?

Comment: You should probably wait until you have a complete line... i.e. don't process a line that doesn't end with a `\n` . But no it ought not to matter that you leave the serial port open.

Comment: Why do you write the data to file? Could you not parse the `data` variable directly? It might make it easier...

Comment: @Floris can you guide me how to do that, yes  tried looking for it, unfortunately i got some other results..

Comment: @Floris -how to check whether a line is complete or not??

Comment: I have written a "possible solution". Not tested - let me know if it gives you trouble.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Here is a thought: parse the data string into chunks that are newline terminated; leave "unfinished" strings in the buffer until the next time around the loop. Untested, this will look something like this:

```
keepThis = ''
while True :
    data=keepThis + ser.read(ser.inWaiting()) # read no.of bytes in waiting
    m = data.split("\n") # get the individual lines from input

    if len(m[-1]==0):    # true if only complete lines present (nothing after last newline)
      processThis = m
      keepThis = ''
    else:
      processThis = m[0:-1]   # skip incomplete line
      keepThis = m[-1]        # fragment

    # process the complete lines:
    for line in processThis:
        if line.startswith( '$GPGGA' ) :
          try :
            lat, _, lon = line.strip().split(',')[2:5] # move inside `try` just in case...
            lat = float( lat )
            lon = float( lon )
            print lat
            print lon
          except :
            pass
```

Comment: i got this error:Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "stack1.py", line 29, in <module>
    get_present_gps()
  File "stack1.py", line 13, in get_present_gps
    if len(m[-1]==0):
TypeError: object of type 'bool' has no len() is something wrong here w.r.t parenthesis in wrong positions???

Comment: i  changed if len(m[-1]==0): to if len(m[-1]0==0:i am getting some random values which are not in the range which we specified, i wanted to  try other method saving data to file and doing same operation, will it make it difference? and what i am not getting here is why are the values out of range(2:5) being printed

Comment: Sorry yes that was a typo - should be `if(len(m[-1])==0):` . Need to take a closer look to understand the other question/comment you posed.

Comment: yet another update, i am taking only 126bytes from serial data and processing to extract single value of coordinates, then i am not getting any error, what should i do to get the newest values(not the ones in the system buffers)??if i  use f.flush() os.fsync(f.fileno()) can i achieve what i want????

Comment: The problem with flushing the buffer is that you will probably "truncate into the middle of the next response". If you look at what I do above, I take "everything in the input buffer" and parse it into "complete" chunks, leaving the incomplete for the next time. You could process only the "last complete chunk" (that would be `processThis[-1]` in the above) - that is the most up to date "good" packet. Then you can leave the rest as it is. Can you try that?

Comment: i tried that...but result was some random alphabets and truncated numbers printing(some of them were outside range[2:5], one more thing to mention here is when i start minicom communication with GPS i am unable to receive data, terminal wont printout any data(is this the indication that something is wrong with GPS), but when i open serial in python, it will work, it shows the number of bits waiting(sometimes with python also it showed 0 bits waiting eventhough module is connected.

Comment: if this is happening sometime in between the running program then only option for program is to print error i will run in.Waiting() bits in a while loop and check if GPS is unable to stream data continuosly)

Comment: Sounds like you have two problems. I would start by debugging the comms issue. Just print every character that comes from the GPS (including new lines) - see if that looks OK. Fix as needed. Then go back to look at parsing etc.

Comment: yeah i am doing the say way, i am icluding print statemnets in the middle of program and check if everything is running ok..